# Changing font with options menu Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts

I'm trying to change the font of a button widget by using the options menu to select the different fonts and sizes. I select the fonts and sizes and get them and store them in the tuple newFont. When I test my code and print the tuple I get ('Helvetica', '13'), ('Times', '112'), etc. based on the options selected in the option menus. I'm a bit confused on why the font and size of the font of the button won't change.

```
from tkinter import *

def manipulateFont(*args):
    newFont = (font.get(), fontSize.get())
    return newFont

window = Tk()

open = Button(window, text="Open", command=open, font=manipulateFont)

"""Option Menu widget for font"""
font = StringVar(window)
font.set("Times")
font.trace("w", manipulateFont)
fontOptions = OptionMenu(window, font, "Arial", "Times", "Helvetica")

"""Option Menu widget for font size"""
fontSize = StringVar(window)
fontSize.set("12")
fontSize.trace("w", manipulateFont)
fontSizeOptions = OptionMenu(window, fontSize, "12", "13", "14", "15")

open.pack(side=TOP)
fontOptions.pack(side=TOP)
fontSizeOptions.pack(side=TOP)
```

Comment: Well, you never change the button's font or font size, so... it's no surprise that it doesn't change, is it? Have you tried actually assigning the selected value to the button's `font` property?

Comment: Yes I have. I was wondering if it's possible to change the font and size in real time when I select a font and size from the option menu.

Comment: You literally just need to add `open['font'] = newFont`...

Comment: You don't want to use names like in `open = Button(window, text="Open", command=open, font=manipulateFont)`. `open` is a Python function to open files. Your button will try to open a file on click, and you'll get a bizarre `TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 1) not found`. And if you later try to open a file, your open reference is now a button...